# Change of variables on a manifold by integrating on the space instead

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Denote
>   $$\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}:=\left\{ \left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right):x_{i}>0\forall1\leq i\leq n\right\} \quad S_{+}^{n-1}=S^{n-1}\cap\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$$
>   for
>   $a=\left(a_{1},\dots,a_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ show that $$\int_{S_{+}^{n-1}}\frac{1}{\left\langle y,a\right\rangle ^{n}}d{\rm vol}_{n-1}\left(y\right)=\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}\frac{1}{a_{1}\cdots a_{n}}$$

My idea was to use a claim proved in class that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}}f(x)d x=\int_{0}^{\infty}c^{n-1}\left(\int_{s_{+}^{n-1}}f(cy)d{\rm vol}_{n-1}\left(y\right)\right)dc$$

The reason I want to use it, is that when integrating over the plane I can do a change of variables, and I do indeed get almost the integrals I want:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}}\frac{1}{\left\langle x,a\right\rangle ^{n}}d x & = & \int_{\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}}\frac{1}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}x_{i}\right)^{n}}d x\\
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
y_{i}= & a_{i}x_{i}\\
d y_{i} & a_{i}d x_{i}
\end{array}\right] & = & \frac{1}{a_{1}\cdots a_{n}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}}\right)^{n}d y\\
 & = & \frac{1}{a_{1}\cdots a_{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cdots\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\right)^{-n}d y_{1}\dots d y_{n}
\end{aligned}$$

But the inner integrals don't converge, and looking at the right side gives:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}c^{n-1}\left(\int_{s_{+}^{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{\langle cy,a \rangle)}\right)^{n}d{\rm vol}_{n-1}\left(y\right)\right)dc= \int_{0}^{\infty}c^{n-1}\left(\int_{s_{+}^{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{c\langle y,a \rangle)}\right)^{n}d{\rm vol}_{n-1}\left(y\right)\right)dc=\int_{0}^{\infty}c^{-1}\left(\int_{s_{+}^{n-1}}\left(\frac{1}{\langle y,a \rangle)}\right)^{n}d{\rm vol}_{n-1}\left(y\right)\right)dc$$

which also fails to converge. It feels really close though, as if the integrals would start from 1 instead of 0, and somehow the problem with the integral of $c^{-1}$ and the last integral of $\mathbb{R}^n_+$ is solved somehow, this gives me exactly the expression wanted..

But I can't just switch the limits of integration, as looking at all the boxes where $x_i\geq 1$, doesn't give the same area as all the balls of radius greater than 1, so I'm a bit stumped as to how to continue..